# Show that $f(x)$ always has value between 1 and 2

Tags: contest-math, recreational-mathematics

Given $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + x}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + a}} + \sqrt{\frac{ax}{ax + 8}}$ for $x \in (0, +\infty)$. How do I prove that $\forall a \geq 0$, $1 < f(x) < 2$?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this? What would you try?

Comment: I guess all three individual terms seem to have values between 0 and 1. Not sure how I should be combining the terms and looking at their sums together. Honestly kinda lost on this so any hints or solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: look at what happens if you allow $x$ to approach $0$ or infinity. see if you can say anything about the behavior of $f$ as $x$ increases

Comment: I think I see how to prove, but haven't worked through the details.  Ignoring the case $a=0$, you can rewrite the equation to be $1/\sqrt(1+a)+1/\sqrt(1+b)+1/\sqrt(1+c)\le 2$ for $abc=8$ ($a$,$b$,$c$ positive).   If $a=b=c=2$ then the inequality holds.  Take any of the three that is bigger than 2 (say $c$), you can show that to maximize the expression on the LHS you can set $a$ and $b$ equal (keeping $c$ fixed and $abc=8$).  Then you can slide $a=b$ down towards zero (while keeping $c=8/(ab)$) and continue increasing the LHS.  So the max of the LHS is at $(a,a,8/a^2)$ for $a\to +\inf$.

Comment: sorry $a \to 0$.